# How to use Maven in Intellj IDEA to install a jar to local repository

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to install a module to local repository so that I can call its classes in another module.

IDEA shows me that the install process has been successfully done.

```
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ commonJT808 ---
[INFO] Installing E:\学习测试\GpsTransferTest\commonJT808\target\GpsTest.jar to C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\com\test\commonJT808\1.0-SNAPSHOT\commonJT808-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing E:\学习测试\GpsTransferTest\commonJT808\pom.xml to C:\Users\ASUS\.m2\repository\com\test\commonJT808\1.0-SNAPSHOT\commonJT808-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

And I have verify in my local repo, [files][1] exist.

However when I try to use it in another module, it doesn't work. The IDE gives me a tip like "failed to read artificat descriptor for commonJT808:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT".

How can I solve it?

Comment: Run the `install` task from the Maven Projects tool window.

Comment: I have tried to run `install:install-file task`,  however it still doesn't work.

Comment: Use [this task](http://i.imgur.com/Pt8m2mp.png).

Comment: In the receiving project you have to tick "Always update snapshots" in Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven   or run `mvn clean install -U`

Comment: @CrazyCoder I have tried the IDEA Maven plugins that you specified, and the maven commends. Both of them don't work.

Comment: I have solved it. The problem is that I have not install the parent artifact of this artifact. After the installation of its parent artifact, this artifact can be referenced in other module. Thank you both :)